# python TypeError: object does not support indexing

Tags: python, typeerror

Here's the faulty bit of my code:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hotspots = []
        self.image = []
        self.item = []

    def newhotspot(*args):
        new = {'Name' : None,
               'id' : None,
               'rect' : None,
               'Takeable' : None,
               'Lookable' : None,
               'Speakable' : None,
               'Itemable' : None,
               'Goable' : None}

        for i in args:
            new[i[0]] = i[1]
        new['id'] = len(self.hotspots)
        self.hotspots.append(new)

CityTrader = Room()

CityTrader.newhotspot(('Name', 'Trader'),
                      ('Takeable', 'Yes'))
```

The goal is to have a dictionary with all the keys set to none but the ones specified.
However, when I run it I get:

```
[...]line 85 in <module>
('Takeable', 'Yes'))
[...]line 44, in newhotspot
new[i[0]] = i[1]
TypeError : 'Room' object does not support indexing
```

Anyone knows why and how to solve this?
It seems to work when it's not wrapped inside a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `self` parameter to `newhotspot()`:

```
def newhotspot(self, *args):
    ...
```

Since `self` will be implicitly passed anyway, it ends up as the first item of `args`.

Answer (score 1):

Every class method must take *self* as it's first argument.

Try this:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hotspots = []
        self.image = []
        self.item = []

    def newhotspot(self, *args):
       new = {'Name' : None,
       'id' : None,
       'rect' : None,
       'Takeable' : None,
       'Lookable' : None,
       'Speakable' : None,
       'Itemable' : None,
       'Goable' : None}

       for i in args:
           new[i[0]] = i[1]
       new['id'] = len(self.hotspots)
       self.hotspots.append(new)

CityTrader = Room()

CityTrader.newhotspot(('Name', 'Trader'),
                      ('Takeable', 'Yes'))
```

Comment: Wrong, class methods take the class as first argument.  Instance methods have `self` as the first parameter.